# Validation error "This value should not be blank" when submitting a form on production website

Tags: forms, symfony, validation, doctrine-orm, symfony5

I'm developing a website using **php 7.4, symfony 5.4 and twig**. This website is deployed on several servers.
On one of the servers (RedHat), a form cannot be submitted. I get the following error 4 times : "[**This value should not be blank.**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fM161.png)".
The messages appear on top of the form and aren't attached to a particular field.

I can't reproduce this error on another server, nor on my development environment...

The problem might comes from a validator but I'm not sure whether it's a symfony or a doctrine error.

The POST data is identical on production server and dev environment :

```
report_selection[iFrame]: 1
report_selection[dteFrom]: 2023-01-30 07:00
report_selection[dteTo]: 2023-01-31 07:00 
report_selection[reportType]: 1
report_selection[size]: 200
report_selection[product]: 1
report_selection[submit]:
```

I assume that the empty field `submit` is not a problem since other forms work fine while having the same field empty.

The database structure is the same on all servers.

Here is the form's code :

```php
   public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
    {
        $bDisplaySize = $options['bDisplaySize'];
        $bDisplayReportType = $options['bDisplayReportType'];
        $bDisplayProduct = $options['bDisplayProduct'];
        $defaultValue = $options['defaultValue'];
        $em = $options['entity_manager'];

        list($H, $m) = explode(":", $iShiftStart);
        $initialFromDate = (new DateTime())->modify('-'.$H.' hour');
        $initialFromDate = $initialFromDate->modify('-1 day');
        $initialFromDate->setTime((int)$iShiftStart, (int)$m, 0);
        $initialToDate = clone $initialFromDate;
        $initialToDate = $initialToDate->modify('+1 day');


        $builder->add(
            'iFrame',
            ChoiceType::class,
            array(
                'label' => 'master.preselection',
                'choices' => [
                    'master.yesterday' => false,
                    'master.today' => false,
                    'master.thisWeek' => false,
                    'master.lastWeek' => false,
                    'master.thisMonth' => false,
                    'master.lastMonth' => false,
                    'master.memomryDate' => false,
                ],
                'attr' => ['onchange' => 'refreshPreselectedChoices()'],
                'choice_attr' => [
                    'master.yesterday' => [],
                    'master.today' => ['selected' => 'selected'],
                    'master.thisWeek' => [],
                    'master.lastWeek' => [],
                    'master.thisMonth' => [],
                    'master.lastMonth' => [],
                    'master.memomryDate' => ['disabled' => true],
                ],

            )
        );

        $builder->add(
            'dteFrom',
            TextType::class,
            array(
                'label' => 'form.from',
                'data' => $initialFromDate->format('Y-m-d H:i'),
                'attr' => array(
                    'style' => 'width:150px;',
                    'oninput' => 'dteFromToCustom()',
                    'onchange' => 'dteFromToCustom()',
                ),
            )
        );

        $builder->add(
            'dteTo',
            TextType::class,
            array(
                'label' => 'form.to',
                'data' => $initialToDate->format('Y-m-d H:i'),
                'attr' => array(
                    'label' => 'form.to',
                    'style' => 'width:150px;',
                    'oninput' => 'dteFromToCustom()',
                    'onchange' => 'dteFromToCustom()',
                ),
            )
        );

        if ($bDisplayReportType) {
            $builder->add(
                'reportType',
                ChoiceType::class,
                array(
                    'label' => 'summaryReport.data',
                    'choices' => array(
                        'summaryReport.type1' => '1',
                        'summaryReport.type2' => '2',
                    ),
                )
            );
        }

        if ($bDisplaySize) {
            $builder->add(
                'size',
                EntityType::class,
                array(
                    'class' => ProductsSizeSpecs::class,
                    'choice_label' => 'rSize',
                    'choice_value' => 'rSize',
                    'placeholder' => '',
                    'label' => 'form.size',
                    'required' => false,
                    'mapped' => false,
                    'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) {
                        return $er->createQueryBuilder('e')
                            ->groupBy('e.rSize')
                            ->orderBy('e.rSize', 'ASC');
                    },

                )
            );
        }

        if ($bDisplayProduct) {
            $builder->add(
                'product',
                EntityType::class,
                array(
                    'class' => Products::class,
                    'choice_label' => 'sNumber',
                    'choice_value' => 'sNumber',
                    'placeholder' => '',
                    'label' => 'master.product',
                    'required' => false,
                    'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) {
                        return $er->createQueryBuilder('e')
                            ->groupBy('e.sNumber')
                            ->orderBy('e.sNumber', 'ASC');
                    },

                )
            );
        }

        $builder->add(
            'submit',
            SubmitType::class,
            array(
                'label' => 'form.submit',
                'attr' => array('class' => 'btn btn-primary'),
            )
        );
    }
```

Other forms use the exact same code with more or less options.

I search a way to debug this on the production server (list/dump of 'blank' fields?).

Any hint will be appreciated, thanks !

Comment: Could you provide more information about, version of the PHP, what kind of error are  you facing, logs, an example of the code

Comment: Thanks for you reply, I added some infos in the initial post. I don't have any particular logs, especially on production environment as this is not an exception or fatal error.

Comment: You have some "if" in your form such "bDisplayReportType" , for example if this attribute is set notBlanck with assert in the entity so it will not be valid even it's not present in the form. So try to put validator directly in the formType and see the result

Comment: I'm not sure what you meant by putting the " validator directly in the formType and see the result". Should I move the Assert from the entity to the Form builder ?

Comment: @Topaze85 yes you can put the constraints directly in the formType  https://symfony.com/doc/current/validation.html#constraints-in-form-classes

Answer (score 0):

Indeed I had some `@Assert\NotBlank` on several columns of an Entity.

**Why** the error was only on this server :

- An instance (db record) of this Entity was `NULL` on those columns (which is an anormal behavior).
- All the instances where retrieved to populate the form's dropdowns (as 'default' data).
- It looks like the validator is checking the submitted 'data' **AND** those 'default' values since they are part of the form.
- There were 4 asserted columns, so that's why I had 4 errors messages.

**What** I've done to find this out :

- Added a `dump($this->form->getErrors())` instruction on the callback processing the submitted form. It displayed the 4 entity's columns giving me hard time.
- Went into db to see the corrupted record, and deleted it.

To prevent this in the future I might change the default values of these columns from NULL to something else, a basic string or a 0 value, and search the process that led to this corrupted record in db.

Thanks for your hints guys !